# Combinatorics: create a 3-digit number out of 2 digits?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, combinatorics

We have a set of two numbers {1,2} an we wish to create a 3-digit number out of the two numbers without order mattering. Here is my approach since there are 2 values for each spot then it's 2^3 since there are three spots and we have 8 total(111,112,121,122,211,212,221,222) which takes care of the order does matter situation. We need to get the total of 4(111,112,122,222) so I was thinking it needs to be divided by 2! to get 4. But it doesn't generalize. Say we take 3 numbers {1,2,3} and try to create a 2 digit number out of them, again it's 3 choices for each spot so 3^2=9(12,21,13,31,23,32,11,22,33) total but that only works for order does matter. We get 6 numbers(12,13,23,11,22,33) where order doesn't matter and I have no idea how to get 6 out of 9. Please help me understand what to do here in the general case.

Comment: Is your question roughly how to construct discrete uniform random variables on a given set given any number of discrete uniform variables on another set?

Comment: No my question is about counting the number of ways to create a number out of digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\binom{n}{k}$ gives you the number of ways you can select $k$ unordered elements out of $n$ *without* *replacement*.

You are looking for the version with replacement, also called a multiset. This is given by what's apparently called [Stanley's symbol](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/select_with_replacement/), which can also be expressed in terms of a binomial coefficient:

$$
\bigg(\binom{n}{k}\bigg)=\binom{n+k-1}{k}
$$

A quick check in [`R`](https://www.r-project.org/) confirms your calculations so far:

```r
stanley <- function(n, k) choose(n+k-1, k)

stanley(2, 3)
> 4

stanley(3, 2)
> 6

stanley(3, 3)
> 10
```

Comment: This answers my question. Thank you so much! I don't have enough reputation to give you points.